# How can I remove the "type" attribute from Html.EditorFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my View, I have a `Html.EditorFor` line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreditEarned, 
     new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

When I look at the rendered HTML, I see that the input has a "type = date" attribute. Is there any way I can use EditorFor and remove the type attribute? This way I can have the desired functionality without causing Edge problems.

```
<input 
    class="form-control datecontrol" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-date="The field Date Credit Earned must be a date." 
    data-val-required="The Date Credit Earned field is required."     
    id="DateCreditEarned" 
    name="DateCreditEarned" 
    type="date" value="6/27/2016">
```

**Update**

I discovered that I can use `Html.TextboxFor` without having any Edge problems (i.e., Edge overriding my Bootstrap datepicker with its own). But I was hoping I could get the same thing done with EditorFor.

Comment: Have you tried the `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` attribute on the model property?

Comment: I hadn't tried it until you mentioned it just now. The rendered HTML is what I need it to be: `<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DateCreditEarned must be a date." data-val-required="The DateCreditEarned field is required." id="DateCreditEarned" name="DateCreditEarned" type="text" value="6/27/2016 12:04:42" />`

Comment: Why would you want to use `EditorFor()` when `TextBoxFor()` generates the correct html?

Comment: Pure laziness. I start with the autoscaffolded code, so the less I have to retype the better I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, making my comment an answer, in ASP.NET MVC You typically do things declaratively in models. In this case a text field was wanted so making the model property like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)] 
public DateTime DateCreditEarned { get; set; }
```

solved the problem.